# Regexp_Replace using joining a table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I wanted to replace data in tableB with data in tableA.
Table A:

| Source_Col | Target_Col |
| --- | --- |
| DB_DEV | DB_UAT |
| CDB_DEV | CDB_UAT |

[image]

I have another table which has one col with the value "Create or replace DB_DEV.SCH.VIEW AS SELECT * FROM CBD_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME".

I wanted to replace DB_DEV with DB_UAT and CBD_DEV with CBD_UAT querying from TableA.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  You want to take a SQL string, parse out the DB name(s), perform a lookup in another table to get their replacements, and substitute them in a new result string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Revised to use tables:

-- Create the source and target string patterns to replace

    create or replace table str_replace (source string, target string);
    insert into str_replace values ('DB_DEV','DB_UAT'),('CDB_DEV', 'CDB_UAT');
    
-- Create the table containing the original strings to be modified

    create or replace table orig_strings (query string, new_query string);
    insert into orig_strings values ('Create or replace view DB_DEV.SCH.V_TABLEA AS SELECT * FROM CDB_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME;',null),('Create or replace view DB_DEV.SCH.V_TABLEB AS SELECT * FROM CDB_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME;',null);
```

--- Query with row_number partition to pick 1st row from Cartesian join

```
select
    os.query,
    regexp_replace(os.query, str.source, str.target) as new_query
from
    orig_strings os,
    str_replace str QUALIFY row_number() over (
        partition by os.query
        order by
            os.query
    ) = 1;
```

-- Results

```
QUERY                                                    
                                                            NEW_QUERY
    Create or replace view DB_DEV.SCH.V_TABLEA AS SELECT * FROM CDB_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME;  Create or replace view DB_UAT.SCH.V_TABLEA AS SELECT * FROM CDB_UAT.SCH.TABLENAME;
    Create or replace view DB_DEV.SCH.V_TABLEB AS SELECT * FROM CDB_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME;  Create or replace view DB_UAT.SCH.V_TABLEB AS SELECT * FROM CDB_UAT.SCH.TABLENAME;

-- Update the table with the modified string

    update orig_strings os
    set os.new_query = regexp_replace(os.query,str.source,str.target) 
    from str_replace str;
    
    select * from orig_strings;
```

-- Results:

```
QUERY                                                    NEW_QUERY
Create or replace view DB_DEV.SCH.V_TABLEA AS SELECT * FROM CDB_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME;  Create or replace view DB_UAT.SCH.V_TABLEA AS SELECT * FROM CDB_UAT.SCH.TABLENAME;
Create or replace view DB_DEV.SCH.V_TABLEB AS SELECT * FROM CDB_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME;  Create or replace view DB_UAT.SCH.V_TABLEB AS SELECT * FROM CDB_UAT.SCH.TABLENAME;
```

Comment: Thank you.  But when I do a join, it doesn't work. So in my case the data , "Create or replace DB_DEV.SCH.VIEW AS SELECT * FROM CBD_DEV.SCH.TABLENAME" is in Table B. So when I have to replace Table B with str-replace Table,  it is not working.

Comment: So just one more table with a single column with strings in it?  I probably would have designed this with tokens instead of literals in the string to aid in replacement.  I’ll update my answer with another table and repost.  If there is a join column to consider please advise, otherwise this is a Cartesian join.

Comment: Yes,  this is a Cartesian join.

Comment: See revision above.  REGEXP_REPLACE used on table data within an update statement to show original and modified string.

Comment: Thank you so much Jim. I am using the same script you have provided. I am not sure why but the code is not updating all the cols. It randomly updates. I am still not able to figure out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Are you using Snowsight or a different UI?  Is it just the update statement that’s not working?

Comment: Hi Jim, I found the issue. Your query works fine. Thank you so much. So, when I was using the cursor, I was updating the target col over and over with the input from the loop. So, when the job completed, I got to see the output for the data that was updated with that last record that came through the cursor. I fixed it.